# Вытащить кусок html через JSOUP

Tags: android, парсер, java

Приветствую! Погуглив эту компоненту, я не нашел исчерпывающих мануалов. Может кто сталкивался? Нужно вытащить из html-странички кусок кода:

```
<div id="schedule"></div>

    <div id="footer" style="margin-top: 60px">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="sidebar">

    <div id="filmlist">

        <ul>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Ледниковый период 4/show_film.t">Ледниковый период 4</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Ледниковый период 4 3D/show_film.t">Ледниковый период 4 3D</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Мадагаскар 3/show_film.t">Мадагаскар 3</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Новый человек паук/show_film.t">Новый человек паук</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Новый человек паук 3D/show_film.t">Новый человек паук 3D</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Новый человек паук IMAX 3D/show_film.t">Новый человек паук IMAX 3D</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Римские приключения/show_film.t">Римские приключения</a></li>

                    </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="future">

        <h3> Скоро: </h3>

        <ul>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Ищу друга на конец света/show_film.t">Ищу друга на конец света</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Космополис/show_film.t">Космополис</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Папа-досвидос/show_film.t">Папа-досвидос</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/film/get/Солдаты удачи/show_film.t">Солдаты удачи</a></li>

                    </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

И разобрать на куски. Как это сделать, я так и не разобрался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на счет мануалов, то  [вот тут есть](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)

описание команд селектора [тут можно посмотреть](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

допустим если тебе нужно откопать все значения под тегом 
`<div id = "future">`

то делаем примерно так:

```
private Document mDoc;
private Elements films;
.....
films = mDoc.select("div#future > li");
```

все записи в films (а их 4) будут прямо с тегом a.
затем в цикле делаешь:

```
String filmLnk = films.get(i).attr("href");
String filmName = films.get(i).text();
```

[еще вот полезно](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)