# HTML парсинг в eclipse

Tags: android-sdk, android, синтаксический-анализ, eclipse, java

Имеется приложения для Android на java в eclipse.
При загрузке программы в textView должны заноситься данные, которые лежат на сайте

```
<div id="pendingEarnings" class="bigNumber">$1.07</div>
```

можно ли как то вытащить данные и запихнуть в textView зная id и class div элемента?

ps. java учу 3 дня всего.

По парсингу страниц прочитал много смного всего, но так ничего и не понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Загляни вот сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/126865/java-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-html-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-jsoup), здесь я приводил полезные ссылки и пример, как парсить страничку HTML

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам хороший [HTML парсер](http://www.nightwhistler.net/htmlspanner). Правда вам придется почистить его и под править под свои нужды.